# MySQL query to populate number of orders in the same month as a separate column in each row of the input table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've an orderdetails table like this:

```
+------------+----------+
| order_date | order_id |
+------------+----------+
| 2017-01-02 | a        |
| 2017-01-31 | B        |
| 2017-02-01 | c        |
| 2017-09-01 | d        |
+------------+----------+
```

And I'm trying to achieve an output table like this below

```
+------------+----------+-------+
| order_date | order_id | count |
+------------+----------+-------+
| 2017-01-02 | a        |     2 |
| 2017-01-31 | B        |     2 |
| 2017-02-01 | c        |     1 |
| 2017-09-01 | d        |     1 |
+------------+----------+-------+
```

I used the below code to insert the values into the table

```
create table orderdetails (order_date date, order_id varchar(1));

insert into orderdetails values 
('2017-01-02','a'), 
('2017-01-31','B'), 
('2017-02-01','c'), 
('2017-09-01','d');
```

I tried the below code to achieve this and unsuccessful. Please help..

```
select *, 
case
when month(order_date) = 1 then count(order_id)
when month(order_date) = 2 then count(order_id)
else 1 as num_orders
end
from orderdetails;
```

Comment: How do you get a `2` in the first 2 rows with the data you show us? What are YOU counting

Comment: What you’re looking for is the GROUP BY statement combined with a JOIN statement. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html or if you’re using MySQL 8 you can use a WINDOW function. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html

Comment: I wanted to count the number of orders placed in the same month in a separate column. The count '2' I entered manually to give an idea to the question I asked. 

Say my table has 2 orders in January and 1 in September and Feb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
SELECT x.*
     , y.total 
  FROM orderdetails x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT DATE_FORMAT(order_date,'%Y-%m')yearmonth
            , COUNT(*) total 
         FROM orderdetails 
        GROUP 
           BY yearmonth
     ) y 
    ON y.yearmonth = DATE_FORMAT(x.order_date,'%Y-%m');
```

Comment: Wonderful.. Thank you so much!